# Convert son class to father class

Tags: c#

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List list = new List();
            list.Add(new A());

            var list2 =
                from p in list
                select p as B;

            Console.WriteLine(list2.First().myString);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }

    class A
    {
        public string myString = "abc";
    }

    class B : A
    {

    }
}
```

How can I solve this?
Thanks

Comment: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
could you please run it?

Comment: @Alon: That is the error - the "as" construct returns null on an unsuccessful cast. He can't cast A to B, so he gets that error. If he used a direct cast (ie, "(B)theA"), he would have gotten an InvalidCastException.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't do that; the list contains an instance of A, you can't cast A to B. You can only cast "upwards" in the inheritance chain, not downwards. So if you change places on A and B in your code, it works:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<B> list = new List<B>();
        list.Add(new B());

        var list2 =
            from p in list
            select p as A;

        Console.WriteLine(list2.First().myString);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}

class A
{
    public string myString = "abc";
}
class B : A { }
```

If you want to convert in the other direction, you need to write code for the conversion:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<A> list = new List<A>();
        list.Add(new B());

        var list2 = list.ConvertAll<B>(a => B.FromA(a));

        Console.WriteLine(list2.First().myString);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}

class A
{
    public string myString = "abc";
}

class B : A
{
    public B() { }

    public static B FromA(A fromInstance)
    {
        B result = new B();
        result.myString = fromInstance.myString;
        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: I understood that already, so how can I solve it? I mean, should I create a method for convert manually?

Comment: @Alon: yes, if you really want that conversion, you will need to do it manually.

Answer (score 1):

`list2.First().myString` will try to access `myString` on a `null` reference. The `as` operator returns `null` if you can't cast. And object-oriented design principles tell us that you can use a *subclass* in any place where you can also use its *superclass* but *not* the other way around. So you're filling your list with instances of `A` and try to cast them to `B`. But they simply aren't instances of `B` so that cast will always fail (and, since you're using `as`, return `null`).

Answer (score 0):

Your program does "convert father class to son class", contrary to your question title. Anyway, that can't be done.

To clarify this:

Try changing class B to the following:

```
class B : A
{
    public string MyStringB { get; set; }
}
```

If you were able to cast A to B, what would the myStringB value be since it was never defined on A?

Answer (score 0):

Create a constructor in B class which takes an instance of A class.

Comment: and use that constructor explicitly

Answer (score 0):

You can create a copy constructor which takes an object of type `A`:

```
class B : A
{
    public B(A copy) {
        myString = copy.myString;
    }
}
```

I'm not too familiar with LINQ, however, so I'm not sure how you'd get it to automatically use this.

Comment: LINQ won't automatically use it, you'd have to invoke it explicitly.

Comment: Would this mean selecting objects of type A and then looping over them later, or is there some way of passing a lambda to LINQ to have it convert them? If there is, which way would be more efficient?